# Questions about metastable van der Waals states

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

This is an excerpt from David Tong's [Statistical Physics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/statphys.pdf):

[image]

My questions:

1. Are those metastable states ("good states") taken from the Maxwell-corrected $pV$-curves (flat lines) or from the uncorrected $pV$-curves as in the figure?

   - If they are referring to the down-going segments between the co-existence curve and the spinodal curve in the figure, how are they connected to the flat lines inside the spinodal region after correction? (The $pV$-curves will be discontinuous.)
2. Any references for the free energy calculation in metastability and the comparison with the free energy in equilibrium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those metastable states ("good states") taken from the Maxwell-corrected -curves (flat lines) or from the uncorrected -curves as in the figure?

The van der Waals metastable states are precisely the uncorrected down-going segments between the co-existence and spinodal curves in the figure. If one traced the flat coexistence part of the isotherms, these segments would lay below (at low volumes) and above it (at high volumes). The metastable states end at the spinodal curve.

> Any references for the free energy calculation in metastability and the comparison with the free energy in equilibrium?

There are different ways to calculate the free energy in the liquid and the vapor phase. Methods go from approximate variational or perturbation theories to integral equations to numerical simulations. Of course, all the numerical methods require a model for the interactions. One of the first simulation studies was the pioneering paper by Hansen, J. P., and Verlet, L. (1969). *Phase transitions of the Lennard-Jones system.* Physical Review, 184(1), 151.

Comment: Then how to go from the end of metastable states to the start of equilibrium states? Do we still have segments with negative compressibility? Or can you show what the $pV$-curve looks like when including the metastable states?

Comment: @Ziyuan The metastable states end at the spinodal line. There is no way to continue them. Remember that metastable states are not unconditionally stable. Sooner or later, the system will find its way toward the stable two-phases configuration.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, normally the substance will go along the flat lines as a mixture of phases. If we put effort we can maintain metastability.  When such metastability ends it will move quickly to the equilibrium/flat lines (or "abrupt phase transition", as in Chapter 11 of James P. Sethna's _Entropy, Order Parameters, and Complexity_).

Comment: @Ziyuan Yes, you have perfectly summarized the situation.